# How to remove login link from YAF.NET forum header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, forum

I can't find good reference in YAF support forum for this issue. I followed these steps from YAF [support forum](http://forum.yetanotherforum.net/yaf_postst6616_Remove-LoginLogout-Link-in-the-header.aspx)...

Comment out these lines in `pages/ForumPage.cs`.

```
if ( TransPage != "LOGIN" )
    header.AppendFormat( String.Format( " | <a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", Forum.GetLink( Pages.login, "ReturnUrl={0}", Server.UrlEncode( Utils.GetSafeRawUrl() ) ), GetText( "TOOLBAR", "LOGIN" ) ) );
```

Build the solution and it's successfully output the `yaf.dll`.

But it still don't work. I'm using YAF version 1.9.0.

I tried other changes but it seems like, the output `yaf.dll` is not effected to my forum. Is there any other ways?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Latest version v1.9.4-BETA3 has a setting that goes into app.config

```
<add key="YAF.AllowLoginAndLogoff" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the YAF solution is setup, but i've had this issue many times.

Try deleting the yaf.dll in your web bin/ directory and then re-add the yaf reference to your web project, rebuild entire solution and deploy.